# How to access one row out of many founded

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I had a problem wit openpyxl but users [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10212502/eric) and [H. Trizi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9813622/h-trizi) solved it. Unfortunately there is another problem. They gave me solution how to select rows that contain certain product name (ABC in this case) but I have no idea how to access search results separately.

[image: Excel report]

This is Eric's code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("report.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.rows:
   if row[4].value == "ABC":
       for cell in row:
           print(cell.value, end=" ")
       print()
```

And this is H. Trizi's:

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("path_to_excel_file")
    df_abc = df[df["Products"] == "ABC"] # this will only contain 2,4,6 rows
```

They both work great when it comes to selecting ALL rows that contain "ABC" product but is there a way to access every single row (and then every cell in it) that contains ABC product name separately?

What I want to achieve ist access every row that has product name ABC separately and then save its cells to variables.

So step by step:
1.Find all rows with ABC product is in rows (2,4,6 in this case)- solved by Eric and H. Trizi
2.Get row 2 and break it down to cells that will be assigned to variables (name, surname, order number etc.)
3. Do the same for row 4
4. Do the same for row 6
5.etc.
PS. Data is available in excel report

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you can just save the dataframe you created and iterate over the rows using e.g. [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) . That will return one row after the other (as a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)) and you can access each column by doing `[1][column_name]` on each item. Happy to elaborate if that looks right to you! *EDIT: that is what jezrael below suggests as well; my links will work for their answer too*

Comment: What is expected output? `List`s ? `List of dictionary` for each filtered row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use very slow [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, row in df_abc.iterrows():
    print (i)
    name = row['name']
    surname = row['surname']
```

Or a bit faster [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for i in df_abc.itertuples():
    name = i.name
    surname = i.surname
```

Another solution is convert filtered `DataFrame` to list of dictionaries by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), it should be fastest:

```
L = df_abc.to_dict(orient='r')

for x in L:
    print (x)
    name = x['name']
    surname = x['surname']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'surname':list('abcdef'),
                   'Products':['ABC','ABC','d','d','ABC','f'],
                   'val':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'name':list('DFERTH')})

print (df)
  surname Products  val name
0       a      ABC    7    D
1       b      ABC    8    F
2       c        d    9    E
3       d        d    4    R
4       e      ABC    2    T
5       f        f    3    H

df_abc = df[df["Products"] == "ABC"]
print (df_abc)
  surname Products  val name
0       a      ABC    7    D
1       b      ABC    8    F
4       e      ABC    2    T
```

---

```
L = df_abc.to_dict(orient='r')
print (L)
[{'surname': 'a', 'Products': 'ABC', 'val': 7, 'name': 'D'},
 {'surname': 'b', 'Products': 'ABC', 'val': 8, 'name': 'F'},
 {'surname': 'e', 'Products': 'ABC', 'val': 2, 'name': 'T'}]

for x in L:
    print (x)
    print (x['name'])
    print (x['surname'])

D
a
{'surname': 'b', 'Products': 'ABC', 'val': 8, 'name': 'F'}
F
b
{'surname': 'e', 'Products': 'ABC', 'val': 2, 'name': 'T'}
T
e
```

EDIT:

For select each value to separately `variable` - it is not necessary, because is possible use `list of dictionary`, select each `dictionary` by indexing and then select each value of dict:

```
#selected first dictionary of list by indexing ([0]) and then dictionary by key (name)
print (L[0]['name'])
D
print (L[0]['surname'])
a

print (L[1]['name'])
F
print (L[1]['surname'])
b

print (L[2]['name'])
T
print (L[2]['surname'])
e
```

Comment: thats a good answer note though that OP wants to *"save its cells to variables."*

Comment: @patrick - hmmm, but not sure what OP need exactly, so write comment under question.

Comment: @jezrael - very helpful and we are pretty close to solve this one but only the last customer gets saved to variables. So after i run the script and then type name variable i only get name of the last customer. Is there a way to assign EVERY customer name to a SEPARATE variable? Name1, Name2 etc.

Comment: yes, it was not quite clear what kind of *saving* was expected @ugabuga77 what are you doing with these afterward, do you want to output them to file, process further?

Comment: @patrick: I'd like to copy it to a file- separate for every customer who ordered ABC product.

Comment: @ugabuga77 - I think it is not pythonic create each variable separately, better is use `dictionary` and then select like edit of my answer.

Comment: @jezrael: you've been more than very helpful, i finally got it. Can even express how much I owe you.